# Gulp is not running successfully on my macOS

Tags: node.js, wordpress, gulp, browser-sync

https://ahmadawais.com/my-advanced-gulp-workflow-for-wordpress-themes/

I am following this tutorials and using the gulfile.js he has offered in the tutorial, but when i am installing the

```
npm install
```

i am getting plenty of issues, so i updated the file. but when I instantiate

```
glup
```

in my macOS terminal its giving me following errors and declining to run the command successfully.

```
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[Browsersync] Watching files...
[23:36:59] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Custom scripts task complete
[23:36:59] Finished 'scriptsJs' after 388 ms
[23:36:59] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Vendor scripts task complete
[23:36:59] Finished 'vendorsJs' after 405 ms
[23:36:59] Starting 'default'...
[23:36:59] Finished 'default' after 135 ms
buffer.js:161
  throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg);
  ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
    at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:161:9)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:131:17)
    at Transform.transform [as _transform] (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/index.js:152:21)
    at Transform._read (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at Transform._write (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at Transform.Writable.write (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at StreamFilter.ondata (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:612:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at StreamFilter.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:271:11)
    at StreamFilter.Readable.push (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:238:10)
    at StreamFilter.Transform.push (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:146:32)
    at StreamFilterCallback (/Users/muzammil/Desktop/Themes/Theme2/node_modules/streamfilter/src/index.js:30:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone caught by this, I just ran into the same issue with a 4-yr old project I'm revisiting. It looks like the gulp-combine-media-queries module hasn't been updated since Node v4 (or thereabouts).

This fork of that module solved the issue for me:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-media-queries

Cheers!